# Regex help for filtering extension number (phone) out of data

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a regex pattern that will match on only the extension number from a string that may contain other phone/fax numbers and names that end in E or X. Need help breaking down a regex pattern or tips to do this more effectively.

I tried playing with a regex pattern and was able to match on extension numbers only when other phone/fax numbers are present.

```
(?i)\s*([Ext]*?[- .]*\d{1,4})([X]*?[- .]*\d{1,4})([Ex]*?[- .]*\d{1,4})
```

From the pattern I have right now i can match on numbers like `Ext. 115`, `X 256`, `Ex 2114` only when no other numbers are present. However when a phone number is present I'll match that first.
Also when a fax is indicated from the string `"Jane Doe 888-888-8888/Fx 888-8888` ill match on `x 888-8888`.
Input strings:

```
 1. "Jane  EXT. 115"  
 2. "Jane X289 FAX 888-888-8888"  
 3. "John Doe-X 241 OR CELL888/8888888"
 4. "Jane Doe 888-888-8888"
 5. "John Doe FX 888-888-8888"
```

Output is:

```
 1. "EXT. 115" 
 2. "X289"
 3. "X 241"
 4. "e 888-888-8888"
 5. "X 888-888-8888"
```

(When there is no extension present)

Comment: could you provide more input/expected output samples?

Comment: can you please add some example that match and other that doesn't match

Comment: Your strings are too ambiguous to ever have a 100% solution. I recommend you instead try to change how you receive the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for your samples

`(?i)\s*((?:Ext|Ex|X(?<!FAX))[- .]*\d{1,4}(?![-\d]))`

https://regex101.com/r/UqJKeE/1

Expanded

```
 (?i)
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           Ext
        |  Ex
        |  X
           (?<! FAX )
      )
      [- .]* \d{1,4} 
      (?! [-\d] )
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Thank you, this covers most of my use cases. Still new to regex and was unaware of the negative look-ahead/behind identifiers. This should allow me to improve for the rest of my cases!